# Can't Use Path in ASP MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use Path() but it has a blue line under it and says, "local variable (path) cannot be referred to until it is declared."  How can I use Path()?

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO

Public Class MessageController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <EmployeeAuthorize()>
    <HttpPost()>
    Function SendReply(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal message As String, ByVal files As IEnumerable(Of HttpPostedFileBase)) As JsonResult


            ' upload files
            For Each i In files

                If (i.ContentLength > 0) Then

                    Dim fileName = path.GetFileName(i.FileName)
                    Dim path = path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName)
                    i.SaveAs(path)

                End If

            Next


    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I have tried but when I capitalize the "P" it just makes it to a lowercase and adds the blue underline in Visual Studio.

Comment: Nevermind, I am an idiot.  I see now (I copied this code from a website) that it uses "path" as a variable name which is a reserved word.  That's why it doesn't work!  To fix, I can just rename `Dim path` to `Dim path1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was using `Dim path` which is not possible because "path" is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = Path.GetFileName(i.FileName)
Dim path As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads")
```

here are the references

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error with the comma at the end.  When I add `fileName)` it just does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I found the problem.  See my comment above please.